# Random failure of networks: The proportion of the core never reaches zero?

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory, network-analysis

I'm currently working with Python's networkX library, simulating the random failure of nodes in a directed network and then evaluating the proportion of the remaining core after each step. Core proportion is the node count of the largest connected component after the removal of a node divided by the original node count of the network.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.sparse as sp
import pandas as pd
import random

N = G.number_of_nodes()                                  
M = 1                   
num_nodes_removed = range(0, G.number_of_nodes(), M)  
simulations = 1000
random_attack_core_proportions = []

for i in range(simulations):
C = G.copy()     # A copy of the original network
proportions = []

for nodes_removed in num_nodes_removed:
    
    if C.number_of_nodes() > 0:
        core = max(nx.weakly_connected_components(C), key=len) # This measures the largest connected component.
        core_proportion = len(core) / N                        # Calculating len(Core) which is no. of remaining nodes and N is the number of the original nodes.
    else:
        core_proportion = 0  
    proportions.append(core_proportion)

    if C.number_of_nodes() > 0:
        node_to_remove = random.choice(list(C.nodes)) 
        C.remove_node(node_to_remove)
        
random_attack_core_proportions.append(proportions)

average_proportions = [sum(proportions)/simulations for proportions in zip(*random_attack_core_proportions)]

plt.xlabel('Number of nodes removed')
plt.ylabel('Proportion of nodes in core')
plt.plot(num_nodes_removed, average_proportions, marker='s')   
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Intuitively, the proportion of nodes in the core should start at **1** and eventually drop to **0** (when all nodes have been removed). However, in my simulations, this is not the case. The initial proportion does indeed start at 1, but it doesn't reach 0 by the end of the simulation. Instead, it converges and remains constant at a certain value. I did check whether the network is weakly connected and it is. One thing I tried and worked but not sure if its correct: The range of num_nodes_removed is not inclusive. Hence, I have to add +1 to it. I am interested in knowing what you guys think.

Comment: Hi! It refers to the size of the largest connected component after the removal of a node divided by the original size of the network.

Comment: It is added now. Thanks.